# How to add a new map supports (Baidu map) for openlayers?

Tags: javascript

Our customer wants to use *Baidu* maps in their website and my pm assigned this task to me. I found that the [OpenLayers](https://drupal.org/project/openlayers) module has good expansibility and I just need to add *Baidu* support.

Has someone made *Baidu* maps work on A Drupal web-site?

Demo:

- http://ec2-54-242-164-149.compute-1.amazonaws.com/samples/baidu/index.html
- https://github.com/shitao1988/baidu/

What steps do I need to take? I guess it is not just to add a new layer in the `openlayers.layers.inc`-file?

I'm a new drupaler without complicated module experience.